# Consume Extension method in non-static class

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

All of the examples for extension methods that I have seen consume the extension method in a class like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ...Call extension method here
    }
}
```

These seem to work because the consuming class is static.  Is there a way to consume an extension method in a non static class like below?  I can't seem to find any examples like this.

I have my Extension Method class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AwesomeApp
{
    public static class LinqExtensionMethods
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> FindItemsBeforeAndAfter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> matchFilling)
        {
            if (items == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
            if (matchFilling == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("matchFilling");
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have my class that consumes the extention method

```
namespace AwesomeApp
{
    public class Leaders : ILeaders
    {
        var leaders = GetAllLeaders();

        var orderedleaders = leaders.OrderByDescending(o => o.PointsEarned);

        var test = orderedleaders.FindItemsBeforeAndAfter(w => w.UserId == 1);
    }
}
```

If I call the extension method from a static class I do not the the 'Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class' error:

```
public class test
{
    public void testfunc()
    {
        List<int> testlist = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        testlist.FindItemsBeforeAndAfter<int>(e => e == 5);

    }
}
```

I have read through all the stackoverflow answers I can find on the non-generic static class error and they deal with writing your extension method but don't deal with consuming it.

So the question is: If using an extension method with a non-static class is not possible then is there any way to do something that works in a similar way?  for example it can be called as .ExtensionMethod not Helper.ExtensionMethod(passedObject)??

**Resolution:**  I thought I cut and pasted the extension method from public class Leaders : ILeaders to its own class so that I could make it static but I actually just copied it.  The compiler error was pointing to the class name so I did not see the extension method still at the bottom of the file.  The error message is accurate and everyone that answered is correct.

Comment: Yes, it's done all of the time. I'm not sure *how* you're getting an error, it should just work.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to use an extension method from a non-static class.  As a first check can you absolutely confirm you DO NOT have a second definition for FindItemsBeforeAndAfter anywhere?

Comment: Your Leaders code as posted is syntactically invalid,  you have var leaders = GetAllLeaders(); which is a Field (ie its not in a method) but you cant use var for fields.

Comment: I did something really stupid and the compiler error was completely accurate but not completely helpful in bailing me out of my own stupidity.  I moved my extension method to a new project, cut (or so I thought) and pasted the extension method in, renamed it, and referenced the new class in the one that uses it.  I didn't actually cut the original out as I had thought so the error is accurate as I still had an extension method at the bottom of public class Leaders : ILeaders.  The compiler error points you to the name of the class not the bottom of the file.  Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> These seem to work because the consuming class is static.

No, that's incorrect. Extension methods definitely don't have to be **consumed** from static classes or static methods.

However, they do have to be *declared* in a class which is:

- Non-nested
- Non-generic
- Static

You appear to be confusing calling with declaring - when you say:

> If I call the extension method from a static class I do not the the 'Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class' error

... you'll only get that if you try to *declare* the method in a class which doesn't satisfy all the above criteria. You should double click on the error to show where it's being generated - I'm sure you'll find it's the declaration, not the use of the method.

Note that your final example (class `test`) is *not* a static class, nor a static method.

Comment: hi , i m confused with question but as per my knowledge op can use extestion method in test class , there should be no error in that ...right?

Comment: @PranayRana: Yes, it should be fine in the test class - and the OP seems to be saying they're already not seeing any errors there.